# Difference between "Reboadcasting" and "Reattaching"

Tags: reattach, pending, rebroadcast

Could anybody explain what the difference between "Reboadcasting" and "Reattaching" is and what I should choose when a Tx is pending?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Reattach: The process of reattaching a transaction is simply doing the proof of work and tip selection process to reattach the
>   transaction to a different part of the Tangle. Reattach once every 30
>   minutes that a transaction remains pending, and then if still pending
>   after 5 reattachments be sure to contact the sender to verify that the
>   transaction wasn’t double spent.
>
> Chances of confirmation are significantly increased with each
>   reattachment
>
> In the future, reattachments will all be "under the hood" within the
>   wallet's functionality, and will never be noticed by the end user.
>
> Rebroadcast: Rebroadcasting is basically sending the exact same
>   transaction to all of your neighbors again. Most of the time, apart
>   from a situation where you're sure that your neighbors didn't get your
>   transactions, reattaching is more useful to get your transaction
>   accepted by the network. Besides some edge cases, you don't need to
>   ever use "rebroadcast".

Source: [Lightguide](https://matthewwinstonjohnson.gitbooks.io/iota-guide-and-faq/getting-started/reattach-vs.html)