# What exactly happens on reattach?

Tags: transaction, iri-node, reattach

IOTA client will **redo the POW** for 2 transactions. But what exactly is happening at the full node?

- How will it keep track of all the reattachments?
- What will happen if I reattach on multiple full nodes?

Comment: your question is already answered [link](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/223/difference-between-reboadcasting-and-reattaching/224#224)

Comment: @TobiMZ It answers part of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "Reboadcasting" and "Reattaching"](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/223/difference-between-reboadcasting-and-reattaching)

Comment: I don't know how do you guys see it as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The re-attached transaction will be stored in local tangle of the full node and broadcasted to neighbors.

The full node won't keep track of the reattachment. The re-attached transaction is seen as a new one. (As it is a new transaction, there is more chance that it get picked by new transactions for validation.)

If you reattach to multiple nodes : every re-attached transaction will be seen a new transaction and broadcasted on the network.

Soon or later one of those will be confirmed, all the other will never be confirmed.